# Standard in-/output stream

Tags: java, stdout, stdin

How is the System class structured/designed with regard to the standard in-/output?

The System class has a public final `out` method that returns a `PrintStream`. Is the `println()` method then a nested method or how does that exactly work if I call `System.out.println();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`out` is a `public static final` variable, and since it's static, one can get `out` as `System.out` (i.e. in a static manner).

`out` is a `PrintStream` which contains the `println()` method, and you're accessing the `println()` method from the `PrintStream` (i.e., from `out`).

Comment: There's also "in" which is defined as an "InputStream" and "err" which is also defined as a PrintStream.